# Java swing JTable RowFilter ignoring symbols

Tags: java, regex, swing, jtable, rowfilter

Here is my code for filtering the `JTable`.  `'text'` is the input text to search in the table.

```
getSorter().setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + Pattern.quote(text)));
```

Here the filtering is case insensitive. how can i ignore certain symbols like `- ( ) +` during the filtering like +88-11 & 8811 should match during filtering.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom implementation of a `RowFilter`.   In the include method:

- Call the `replaceAll()` method on your string to remove the special characters that you want to exclude.
- Then search for a match to your search pattern.
- Return a true/false depending on if it matches.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you will be able to adopt the following pattern(which completely satisfies your criteria) to your required pattern:

```
String pattern = "([\\Q+-*/\\E]?+\\d+)+"
```

**Simple input:**

```
+25+36
25+36*36
2536
```

And similar other, which will results in exactly one match.

**The way it works:**

1. `[\\Q+-*/\\E]` is to match any one of `+, -, *, /` and `?+` is put afterwards as a quantifier: a `X?+` means that `X` occurs once or not at all.
2. `\\d+` is a pattern which matches *one or more* digits
3. and letting `X = [\\Q+-*/\\E]?+\\d+`, `(X)`: matches `X` as a capture group and `(X)+` means that the group will appear at least once or more.

Check out the [**Pattern class documentation**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).